# What different between "typeSpecifier functionPointer = & definedFunction" and "typeSpecifier functionPointer = definedFunction"?

Tags: c++, function-pointers, std-function

Please considering the following example first (this is a part of the code from Cplusplus.com):

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <functional>   // std::function, std::negate

int half(int x) {return x/2;}

int main () {
  std::function<int(int)> fn1 = half;                    // function
  std::function<int(int)> fn2 = &half;                   // function pointer
  std::cout << "fn1(60): " << fn1(60) << '\n';
  std::cout << "fn2(60): " << fn2(60) << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

What different between fn1 and fn2 in the examle? 
Does that mean that fn1 will COPY the function "half", whereas fn2 is just point to that function. 
The comments by Cplusplus.com imply they're different ; but I've heard from some video said that they're the same and the operator "&" is just optional. 
So what is the truth? please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `typeSpecifier` is an object, then there is no practical difference in most cases. In your code, using `half` and `&half` does exactly the same. It's still worth noting that there are two different effects involved:

### Function-to-pointer conversion

```cpp
auto f = function;
```

This forces an implicit conversion of `function` to an object, and is called *function-to-pointer* conversion:

> An lvalue of function type T can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to T”.
> The result is a pointer to the function.

- [[conv.func] p1](https://eel.is/c++draft/conv#func-1)

Note that your code does not perform *function-to-pointer* conversion explicitly, because you implicitly call [the following constructor](https://eel.is/c++draft/func.wrap.func.con#lib:function,constructor____):

```cpp
// You end up calling this with F = int(&)(int)
// i.e. a reference to a function taking int and returning int.
// (See https://cdecl.plus/?q=int%28%26%29%28int%29 for learning type syntax)
template<class F>
function(F&& f);
```

This constructor uses [`std::decay_t`](https://eel.is/c++draft/meta.trans.other) and performs *function-to-pointer conversion* internally.

### Taking the address of a function with `&`

```cpp
auto f = &function;
```

This takes the address of the function explicitly:

> The operand of the unary `&` operator shall be an lvalue of some type `T`.
> The result is a prvalue.
>
> - [...]
> - Otherwise, the result has type "pointer to `T`" and points to the designated object or function.

- [[expr.unary.op] p3](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.unary.op#3)

In your example, you still call the aforementioned constructor. However, this time you are passing in a "function pointer" [`int(*)(int)`](https://cdecl.plus/?q=int%28%2A%29%28int%29), not "function reference" [`int(&)(int)`](https://cdecl.plus/?q=int%28%26%29%28int%29). The end result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

There's no practical difference.  The reference to function decays to a pointer when we construct a `std::function` from it.

In contexts where it looks like a copy would happen, the reference decays immediately to pointer, just as in C:

```
int main()
{
    auto f1 = half;
    auto f2 = &half;

    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(f1),decltype(f2)>);
}
```

Comment: @user17732522, corrected this answer - does that look correct to you?